# Zend Framework 2 Codeception integration

Tags: php, testing, zend-framework2, codeception

I would like to use codeception as a testing framework in my existing zend framework 2 project. I installed codeception via composer but i dont know what to do next to get my first tests running.

I found the following github file but  i dont really understand for what this is good for.

[ZF2 Module - Codeception](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/master/src/Codeception/Module/ZF2.php)

Can someone tell me what to do next ?

THX

Answer (score 0):

Since acceptance tests are not FW dependent (Codeception accesses your web application via URL), you shouldn't have problems with running those tests. I was following these great tutorials from Jeffrey, and I really advice you check them out if you have no idea where to start: https://tutsplus.com/course/modern-testing-in-php-with-codeception/

However, I still didn't figure out how to configure CC to run functional tests on ZF2 (I think this is the only hard part, since form here on you just use pre-defined TestGuy methods), neither I found any examples online, so I really hope that someone who got this working will be able to provide a more complete answer or maybe even share a config example. In case I find a way I'll update my answer at that point.